# Navigation view inside tab.Panel doesn't animate

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a TabPanel container and one of it's views is a NavigationView. When I push another view into this NavigationView, it doesn't slide with an animation, it just appears immediately. Is there something wrong with my layout? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code since we're not magician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. NavigationView had a card layout in it's config. Removed it and now it works.